# Matrix into JTable

Tags: java, swing, file, matrix, jtable

I need to fill a JTable with a static 2D array. I've created this model for the `JTable`:

```
 public class InsertMatToJTable extends AbstractTableModel{

   String titre[] = {"age real", "sex real", "chest real", "resting_blood_pressure real","serum_cholestoral real","fasting_blood_sugar real","resting_electrocardiographic_results real","maximum_heart_rate_achieved real","exercise_induced_angina real","oldpeak real","slope real","number_of_major_vessels real","thal real", "class"};

   String line;

    float mat[][]= new float[270][13];

    float matrice_normalise[][];

    int i = 0,j=0;

    public void InsertMatToJTable()
    {

try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("fichier.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
                            while (st1.hasMoreTokens())
                            {mat[i][j]=Float.valueOf(st1.nextToken()).floatValue(); 
                                                        j++;

                           if (st1.hasMoreTokens()!=true)   i++;
                            }      
            }
            br.close();
      }catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();}

      Normalisation norm = new Normalisation(mat);

   // for(i=0;i<270;i++)
    //{for(j=0; j<14;j++)
    //{matrice_normalise[i][j]=norm.mat_normalised[i][j];
    //}
      matrice_normalise=norm.mat_normalised;


    }
 @Override
   public int getRowCount() {
    return 270*13;
  }

 @Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return 13;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return  matrice_normalise[rowIndex][columnIndex];
}

public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
    return titre[columnIndex];

}
    }
```

Basically, this code reads from a text file, each line contains 13 numeric values, and stores them into a static matrix, then applies some other treatment called "normalisation".

The problem here seems to be in the "getValueAt" function. I have this error everytime :

```
         Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
         at prodm.InsertMatToJTable.getValueAt(InsertMatToJTable.java:62)
```

First, I need to know if this code actually does what I think does, which is storing the data in the matrix the same way it is stored in the text file.

And second, I really have no idea about what's wrong with the getValueAt function ?

Also, I have noticed something else. There's definitely something wrong with this part :

```
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
                            while (st1.hasMoreTokens())
                            {mat[i][j]=Float.valueOf(st1.nextToken()).floatValue(); 
                                                        j++;
                                                       if (j==13) {i++;j=1;}
                            }
```

It reads from the file, but it doesn't store the data the way it should. Basically, it introduces a "shift", starting from the second line. For exemple, what should be stored at  [1][0] is at [1][1], [2][0] is in [2][2]...etc.

Comment: If this were my code, I would not have file reading code inside of my table model class. These two bits of functionality need to be kept separate. I'd also be sure to test that my file reading works in isolation, and would do my file reading off of the Swing event thread.

Comment: getRowCount() has to be wrong.. The rows are 270. The number of elements are 270*13...

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, Hovercraft.

Comment: Lews, that's just some tests I was doing, just to be sure.

Comment: One main reason to separate concerns, and to do it now, is so you can isolate parts of your code to see what works and what doesn't work. It's much easier debugging a small program than a large one.

Comment: Also, if you are posting code here for others to help you with, please put in the effort to only post well formatted code. It can be incredibly difficult to figure out what another person's code may be doing that you really don't want to make it any harder by having your code indentation be all over the place. Since you're asking volunteers to put in effort to help you, it's not asking too much to ask you to put in effort to format your code well.

Comment: Yes, I know, and I'm sorry for that.

Comment: When you read a line you have to reset the j variable to 0 for the next line.

Comment: Yeah I don't know why I deleted that. Anyway, now the matrix is filling. But the jTable is displaying only 0.0s, even when I link it with the matrix I just filled.

Comment: Please help ? I still have the same issue.

Comment: I'd be concerned with this statement `matrice_normalise=norm.mat_normalised` as it's the only piece of the code we can't see

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have written:

```
public void InsertMatToJTable()
```

but you should have written:

```
public InsertMatToJTable()
```

Notice that there is no `void` in the second snippet.

You have declared a method called `InsertMatToJTable` and not the constructor of the class with the same name. Therefore, when you invoke `new InsertMatToJTable()` you invoke the default no-args constructor and your code is never run, leaving your matrix remains uninitalized, hence the `NullPointerException`.

To avoid these kind of typo issues, add logs to your code and use a debugger to find problems.

Here is an example demo of a working code.

```
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class TestTables {

    private static final int ROWS = 270;
    private static final String titre[] = { "age real", "sex real", "chest real", "resting_blood_pressure real", "serum_cholestoral real",
            "fasting_blood_sugar real", "resting_electrocardiographic_results real", "maximum_heart_rate_achieved real",
            "exercise_induced_angina real", "oldpeak real", "slope real", "number_of_major_vessels real", "thal real", "class" };

    public static class InsertMatToJTable extends AbstractTableModel {

        private float[][] matrice_normalise;

        public InsertMatToJTable(float[][] matrice_normalise) {
            this.matrice_normalise = matrice_normalise;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return matrice_normalise.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return titre.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return matrice_normalise[rowIndex][columnIndex];
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
            return titre[columnIndex];

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestTables.class.getSimpleName());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                float[][] matrix = new float[ROWS][titre.length];
                Random random = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                        matrix[i][j] = random.nextFloat() * 100;
                    }
                }
                InsertMatToJTable model = new InsertMatToJTable(matrix);
                JTable table = new JTable(model);
                JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
                frame.add(scroll);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I was in a kind of rush to be honest, I didn't enough attention to the details. Thank you very much.

Comment: @El-HadjChikhaoui the problem in your code reading the File is that you reset `j` to `1` instead of `0`. Replace `j = 1;` with `j = 0`

Comment: Well that's what I did first. But I got an 'Out of Bound' error, from the rowcount (or columncount) method.

Comment: @El-HadjChikhaoui Take a look at how I do it in my example and try to perform something similar.