# Issue with getValueAt

Tags: java, file, matrix, jtable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Matrix into JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552377/matrix-into-jtable)

Seems to be a problem with this function. I have created a model for a jTable, but it's not getting the values I need. Here's the code :

```
public class InsertMatToJTable extends AbstractTableModel{
String titre[] = {"age real", "sex real", "chest real", "resting_blood_pressure real",  "serum_cholestoral real","fasting_blood_sugar real","resting_electrocardiographic_results real","maximum_heart_rate_achieved real","exercise_induced_angina real","oldpeak real","slope real","number_of_major_vessels real","thal real", "class"};
    String line;
    float mat[][]= new float[370][13];
    float matrice_normalise[][]=new float[270][13];;
    int i = 1,j=1;
    Vector data;
public void InsertMatToJTable()
    {data= new Vector();
 try {
              FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("fichier.txt");
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
                            while (st1.hasMoreTokens())
                            {mat[i][j]=Float.valueOf(st1.nextToken()).floatValue(); 
                                                        j++;
                                                       if (j==13) {i++;j=1;}
                            }  

             }
             br.close();
         }catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();}

         Normalisation norm = new Normalisation(mat);

   // for(i=0;i<270;i++)
    //{for(j=0; j<14;j++)
    //{matrice_normalise[i][j]=norm.mat_normalised[i][j];
    //}
      matrice_normalise=norm.mat_normalised;


    }

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return 270;
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return 13;
}

@Override
 public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return matrice_normalise[rowIndex][columnIndex];
}



public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
    return titre[columnIndex];

}
    }
```

The text file reading is done. The `matrice_normalise=norm.mat_normalised;` part also works. I've tested them apart from each other and they worked.

However, the table is filled with 0.0, it's not getting the values from `matrice_normalise`.

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice. Instead, ask yourself why you don't get answers in your initial question. You could for example answer to the comments you already had, improve your code formatting, etc.

Comment: And posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org)